# how to earn the average of two diffrenet store procedure with two different tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a store procedure with the result like this:

```
Aaa Bbb Ccc Ddd Eee Average
2   7   5   4   5   5
```

And I have another store procedure with the result like this:

```
Fff Ggg Hhh Iii Jjj Kkk Average
28  6   7   5   6   6   6
```

Now I wanna have the average of two average column above!
What can I do?
just notice that these two store procedures are the result of different tables!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

Insert both results in a temp table and calculate the average from the temp table

```
create table #tmp
 (col1 int,col2 int,col3 int,col4 int,col5 int,col6 int,Average int)

insert into #tmp (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,Average)
exec proc1

insert into #tmp 
exec proc2


select sum(Average)/2.0 from #tmp
```

## [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/475ae/1)

**Another option** would be to make the Average variable in both the procedure as OUTPUT parametrer and store the outputs from both the procedure in to variables and calculate the average from the variables

Comment: :when I execute this:create table #tmp
 

insert into #tmp 
(col1 int,col2 int,col3 int,col4 int,col5 int,col6 int,Average int)
exec financial

insert into #tmp (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,Average)
exec portfolio


select sum(Average)/2.0 from #tmp, It MAKES THIS ERRORS: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure avag, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'insert'.

Comment: please note that create table #tmp has a column list along with it

Comment: create table #tmp
 (col1 int,col2 int,col3 int,col4 int,col5 int,col6 int,Average int)

Comment: just one problem?? it works correctly just for the first time, because for second time it considerd the previous amount too, but I don't want it

Comment: I mean I should remove the previous amount from @tem, what can I do?

Comment: truncate table before inserting